# Java Scanner without advancing to the next line?

Tags: java

I'm using `Scanner.nextLine()` to get input. Is there a way to not go to the next line when the enter key is pressed?

Sample code:

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    input=sc.nextLine();
    ...
}
```

When the user presses enter, the current line is captured by the scanner and further input is on the next line. Is there a way for the user to press enter to send the input, but still stay on the same line for the next piece of input?

Comment: Give some examples of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: So based on the question so far, I take it you want the user to input a multi-line piece of data without interruption?  Or are you talking about the display of the user's input on-screen, with no manual line breaks (if so, then `Scanner` is unrelated).

Comment: I'm talking about the display of the newline character. Is there a way to stop the newline from being outputted? (but still send data to Scanner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is essentially "can I read an enter keypress using `Scanner` without moving the cursor on-screen?" then I believe the answer is no.  Java's `Scanner` isn't really setup to function that way.  You may be able to find a library that will allow you to accomplish this.  Unfortunately I don't know of one. :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next()`, but be advised that `next()` operates on tokens. The method will return anything in your line up to the first space that it encounters.